# Is "Wrong side business" used in real life?

Tags: australian-english, aboriginal-english

In the film "Australia", the phrase "Wrong side business" (or "Wrong sided"?) is used as slang for sex.

It sounds like typical Australian Aboriginal English. Wikipedia's article on the topic gives a [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_Aboriginal_English#Business) for "business" by itself, though not "wrong side business"

> **Business**
>
> Many Aboriginal people use the word business in a distinct way, to
>   mean matters. Funeral and mourning practices are commonly known as
>   Sorry Business. Financial matters are referred to as Money Business,
>   and the secret-sacred rituals distinct to each sex are referred to as
>   Women's Business and Men's Business.

However, I've lived in Sydney most of my life, and I haven't ever heard "Wrong side business". Is it used in real life?

Comment: *Illicit* activities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can say, after searching, that the answer is, **no**.

I searched Google, "wrong side business" and got 1 million+ hits.

Narrowed down by "-Australia -Dave -Seaman -mix -nualla" and got 258k hits, most of which were still about the soundtrack or song.

-Wehbba and Propulse, -Amazon, -Wehbba, -artists, and I got three whole pages, with only four results using it as *sex*. The most frequent uses were

- being in the wrong *side business* (as having a sideline that's not profitable)
- things referring to using the *wrong side* (driving on the wrong side of the road, etc.)

Narrowed further by region (Australia) yielded 1 hit, about the song.

This may be invalid as evidence, but it seems sound to me.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong side business is referred to extensively in Xavier Herbert's Australian classic *Poor Fellow My Country*. It means to conduct a secret sexual liaison, possibly between indigenous people of the wrong skin sign or blackfellas and whitefellas.

Answer (score 0):

It's referring to the wrong side of the law.
In colonial days it was illegal for white men to have sex with aborigines, although many did.

Comment: You seem to have a point there. Can you support your argument?

Comment: Hello Alan. Please give some supporting evidence for what looks like a very good answer (so that people who write what don't look like very good answers can reasonably be asked to provide evidence too). (Also, it will round out your answer.)